# Create a list of variables selectInput based on the CVS file

Tags: r, shiny

I am developing an app, using Shiny (with R Studio), and I want to create a `selectInput` with different countries. As they are many, instead of writing all of them, I would like to use a `.csv` file where there are already listed the different country's names.

Does anyone know how can I create a list of variables for my `selectInput` based on the `.csv` file?

```
selectInput("country", "Country:",
        list(
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a file global.R you can load the csv file on start and create a variable with the country names (e.g., country_names <- read.csv("your_file.csv"). Then in your selectInput you would add choices = country_names. If the selectInput doesn't find the variable you may need to use <<- to assign the file content to the country_names variable (i.e., country_names <<- read.csv("your_file.csv")).

Comment: Hello again! Thanks for the answer: it worked perfectly

Now I have another question. If I have this matrix:

   Country Sp
1 Portugal Cc
2    Spain Cc
3   France Cc
4    Italy Cm

And I want to list just the countries where "Sp=Cc" (Portugal, Spain and France), do you know how can I do it?